# Changing ArcGIS Viewer for Flex page title?

Tags: arcgis-flex-viewer

When working with the ArcGIS Viewer for Flex application is it possible to change to title page tab to something else e.g. sometitlepage.com or will the Internet police come for me if I try to alter this setting?

was going to post an image but cannot because I'm 'new'.

link here - http://i1100.photobucket.com/albums/g417/jdsegars/junkphotos/pagetitletoremore.png?t=1311342928

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can definitely change the title of the page.

From what I remember, the title you're referring to is set in index.mxml (they have another title in config.xml as well, but I believe that's the title that appears in the application itself).

That's if you're working with the source and compiling it.  If you are working with the pre-compiled, you'll need to change it by opening index.html and changing the title tag.